# Adjust resize does not work in API 22 with AppCompat on Xamarin.Forms

Tags: android, xamarin, android-appcompat, xamarin.forms

I have a Xamarin.Forms project on Android and I want to use "AdjustResize" as the default method for dealing with the soft keyboard. I do this by setting it in `OnCreate` like this:

```
[Activity(Label = "TestWhite.Droid", Icon = "@drawable/icon", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
public class MainActivity : FormsAppCompatActivity
{
  protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
  {
    FormsAppCompatActivity.ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.toolbar;
    FormsAppCompatActivity.TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.tabs;

    base.OnCreate(bundle);

    global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);

    Window.SetSoftInputMode(SoftInput.AdjustResize);

    LoadApplication(new App());
  }
}
```

Since I have updated to `AppCompat`, `AdjustResize` does not work with API 22, while it still works with API 19.

The problem can be tested very easily with an application containing just one page containing an a scroll view and an editor at the bottom of the page:

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializePage();
}

void InitializePage()
{
    var editor = new Editor
    {
        VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
        HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
        HeightRequest = 200,
    };

    var tallLayout = new StackLayout
    {
        HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
        Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal,
        HeightRequest = 450, 
        BackgroundColor = Color.Lime,
    };

    var layout = new StackLayout
    {
        Orientation = StackOrientation.Vertical,
        VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
        HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
        Children = { tallLayout, editor },
    };

    var scrollView = new ScrollView
    {                
        VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
        HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand, 
    };
    scrollView.Content = layout;

    Content = scrollView;
}
```

With API 19 when the user clicks on the `Editor`, the view gets pushed up so that the user can see what he's writing. With API 22, instead, the keyboard just appears on the view, hiding the  `Editor`. Any ideas about the reason behind this behaviour?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the OnCreate method of your MainActivity you should set your input mode to AdjustResize. Then, to deal with the android bug reported [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=5497), you can use the utility class below (originally converted from java code by @user1658602). Happy Coding!

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
    base.OnCreate(bundle);

    Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);

    Window.SetSoftInputMode(SoftInput.AdjustResize);

    AndroidBug5497WorkaroundForXamarinAndroid.assistActivity(this);

    ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.toolbar;
    TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.tabs;

    LoadApplication(new App());

}

public class AndroidBug5497WorkaroundForXamarinAndroid
{

    // For more information, see https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=5497
    // To use this class, simply invoke assistActivity() on an Activity that already has its content view set.

    // CREDIT TO Joseph Johnson (http://stackoverflow.com/users/341631/joseph-johnson) for publishing the original Android solution on stackoverflow.com

    public static void assistActivity(Activity activity)
    {
        new AndroidBug5497WorkaroundForXamarinAndroid(activity);
    }

    private Android.Views.View mChildOfContent;
    private int usableHeightPrevious;
    private FrameLayout.LayoutParams frameLayoutParams;

    private AndroidBug5497WorkaroundForXamarinAndroid(Activity activity)
    {
        FrameLayout content = (FrameLayout)activity.FindViewById(Android.Resource.Id.Content);
        mChildOfContent = content.GetChildAt(0);
        ViewTreeObserver vto = mChildOfContent.ViewTreeObserver;
        vto.GlobalLayout += (object sender, EventArgs e) => {
            possiblyResizeChildOfContent();
        };
        frameLayoutParams = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams)mChildOfContent.LayoutParameters;
    }

    private void possiblyResizeChildOfContent()
    {
        int usableHeightNow = computeUsableHeight();
        if (usableHeightNow != usableHeightPrevious)
        {
            int usableHeightSansKeyboard = mChildOfContent.RootView.Height;
            int heightDifference = usableHeightSansKeyboard - usableHeightNow;

            frameLayoutParams.Height = usableHeightSansKeyboard - heightDifference;

            mChildOfContent.RequestLayout();
            usableHeightPrevious = usableHeightNow;
        }
    }

    private int computeUsableHeight()
    {
        Rect r = new Rect();
        mChildOfContent.GetWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(r);
        if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt < BuildVersionCodes.Lollipop)
        {
            return (r.Bottom - r.Top);
        }
        return r.Bottom;
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, this is not really a solution, because I want to use `AdjustResize` and not `AdjustPan` :)

Comment: That's reasonable. Did some more searching and I think you should take a look at this other stackoverflow question that describes a bug with the input mode and how to fix it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34013548/xamarin-forms-2-0-appcompat-android-keyboard-mode
Hope this helps!

Comment: This actually helps a lot! It solved the problem. I don't know if you can, but if you post it as an answer I will mark it as accepted :)

Comment: Doesn't work on some devices. For example Galaxy Tab A with Android 8.1